# What will be eigne vectors of 2x 2 symmetric Toeplitz

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a symmetric Teopliz 2x2 matrix I took following steps

taking a matrix

```
A = |2  1|
    |1  2|
```

now their `eigen values = 3 and 1`

when I tried to solve for v11 and v12 for eigen value 3

I stuck at `v11 = v12`

if I take `v1 = c` then 
eigen vector is

```
v11 = c |1|
v12     |1|
```

Now how to find c?

I know I am missing a little concept here please help.

---

I checked with MATLAB it is showing following result of v1

```
v1  =    |0.7071|
         |0.7071|
```

that is showing c = sqrt(1/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot find $c$. Eigenvectors are not unique. If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $cv$ is an eigenvector of $A$ for any $c\neq 0$ with the same eigenvalue since

$$ A(cv) = c\cdot Av = c\cdot \lambda v \Longrightarrow \lambda (cv).$$

At best you can determine $v$ up to a constant multiple. You *could* get a unique eigenvector if you required it to be a unit vector, but this only works if the eigenvalues have geometric multiplicity one. Otherwise there is inherent non-uniqueness since the eigenvalue (by definition of having geometric multiplicity greater than one) would correspond to multiple linearly independent eigenvectors.

I struggled with this myself for a while in undergrad. It's probably not that uncommon a mental disconnect, especially when first learning linear algebra.

Comment: I checked with MATLAB that is saying c = 0.7071

Comment: This ties into the comment that I made about normalization. If you normalize the vector $(1,1)$ to be a unit vector, you need to divide by $\sqrt{2}$ which is precisely where the factor of $0.707107\ldots$ comes from. Many software will give you normalized eigenvectors since that's usually what we want anyway.

Comment: Think of it this way: the set of eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\lambda$ forms a vector space (prove this yourself if you need to). Selecting some $v_1,v_2,...$ is choosing a basis and there is no unique choice of basis for any vector space (except the zero space, but that is kind of trivial).